# How to remove gmt from postgreSQL db across date columns?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, momentjs

I am using PostgreSQL in my application. Simply I have declared a particular model attribute as sale_date and have set its data type to Date as follows:

```
       //definition in backend model
       sale_date: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
       }
```

And I am using moment on the frontend which is on react. I am giving the user a calendar option to select a date and setting the time as 00:00:00 so that the DB does not pick the local time. However, one issue I am facing is that it automatically adds +05 to the time which is the timezone I am currently in.

```
2021-06-01 05:00:00+05
```

Here because of +05, the time became 05:00:00 automatically, how to avoid this, I need time to stay 12am always so that the calendar date does not change even if I upload a document at 11:00 pm.

Using moment like this on the frontend

```
        //From front-end implementation
        sale_date = moment
              .utc(object.sale_date)
              .format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00Z");
```

How do I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `.utcOffset()` can be helpful for your case.

```js
const date = moment().format();

const date2 = moment
  .utc(date)
  .utcOffset(0)
  .format();
  
  console.log(date);
  console.log(date2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

[Documentation of utf offset](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)